Layout on iPhone in browser breaks Firefox
The layout on the iPhone in the browser breaks exactly when you open it on the phone
I tried changing the px to vh, but there was no result.
Set up -moz & -webkit no result
Has anyone encountered similar behavior on an iPhone in Firefox? Everything works fine in the browser in devtools.
return (
  <Block>
    <Container>
      <List>
        <Item>
          <El onClick={handleCatalog} isactive={catalogOpened}>
            <IcnCat />
            <Title>Каталог</Title>
          </El>
        </Item>
        <Item onClick={() => handleListItemsCount}>
          <Link to={PATH.lists.link()}>
            <IcnFav />
            <Title>Закладки</Title>
            {rootStore.listsStore.listsItemsCount > 0 && (
              <Num>{rootStore.listsStore.listsItemsCount}</Num>
            )}
          </Link>
        </Item>
        <Item onClick={() => handleCountItems}>
          <Link to={PATH.cart.link()}>
            <StyledIcnCart />
            <Title>Корзина</Title>
            {rootStore.cartStore.listCartCountQty > 0 && (
              <Num>{rootStore.cartStore.listCartCountQty}</Num>
            )}
          </Link>
        </Item>
        <Item
          onClick={() => {
            handleOrdersCountSales
            fetchNewsList
          }}
        >
          <Link to={PATH.orders.index.link()}>
            <StyledIcnOrder />
            <Title>Заказы</Title>
            {rootStore.ordersTabsStore.ordersSalesCount > 0 && (
              <Num>{rootStore.ordersTabsStore.ordersSalesCount}</Num>
            )}
          </Link>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <El onClick={() => handleOpenUser} isactive={userOpened}>
            <StyledIcnUser />
            <Title>Профиль</Title>
          </El>
        </Item>
      </List>
    </Container>
  </Block>
)

   `export const Block = styled.div`
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: auto;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: ${vars.zindex.mobpanel};
        background: ${vars.color.brand};
        user-select: none;
    `
     `export const List = styled.ul`
         display: flex;
         align-items: flex-start;
         justify-content: space-between;
         height: 60px;
         padding-top: 12px;
      `
      `export const Item = styled.li``
         const stylesEl = css`
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: top;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         font-weight: 500;
         font-size: ${vars.font.small};
         line-height: ${lineHeight(vars.font.small, '20px')};
         text-align: center;
         color: ${vars.color.white};
         transition: color ${vars.trans.base};
         &:hover {
           color: ${vars.color.linksLighten};
         }
        `
        export const Link = styled(NavLink)`
         ${stylesEl}
         
        export const El = styled.div<IsActiveProps>`
          ${stylesEl};
          cursor: pointer;

          ${(props) =>
             props.isactive &&
           css`
            color: ${vars.color.linksLighten};
            pointer-events: none;
          `}

          export const Title = styled.b`
            display: block;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: ${vars.font.small};
            line-height: ${lineHeight(vars.font.small, '20px')};

          const stylesIcn = css`
             display: inline-block;
             vertical-align: top;
             width: 20px;
             height: 20px;
             flex: 0 0 auto;

          export const IcnCat = styled(IcnCatalog)`
             ${stylesIcn}
           `
          export const IcnFav = styled(IcnBookmark)`
             ${stylesIcn}
           `
          export const StyledIcnCart = styled(IcnCart)`
             ${stylesIcn}
           `
          export const StyledIcnOrder = styled(IcnOrder)`
             ${stylesIcn}
           `
          export const StyledIcnUser = styled(IcnUser)`
             ${stylesIcn}
            `
          export const Num = styled.span`
             position: absolute;
             right: 0;
             top: -5px;
             display: inline-block;
             vertical-align: top;
             border-radius: 10px;
             background: ${vars.color.linksLighten};
             color: ${vars.color.white};
             text-align: center;
             font-weight: 700;
             font-size: ${vars.font.mini};
             line-height: 1;
             padding: 2px 4px;
            `

It looks like this After clicking on the directory, the menu drops

After clicking on the catalog, the menu drops

